# Widget parameter default value is ignored

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a widget that accepts two user-defined parameters: location, and background.

The location selector works perfectly and defaults to what my `LocationQuery` `defaultResult` specifies. But the background selector for some reason ignores my `BackgroundQuery` `defaultResult` and XCode throws this warning:

> Error getting AppIntent from LNAction: AppIntent has missing parameter value for 'background'. You may need to set a default value in the initializer of your @Parameter, or using the default method on your Query.
> No AppIntent in timeline(for:with:)

Why isn't it working as the location selector does?

```swift
struct BackgroundQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [String]) ->  [WidgetBackground]  {
        [
            WidgetBackground(id: "Background1"),
            WidgetBackground(id: "Background2")
        ].filter { identifiers.contains($0.id) }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() -> [WidgetBackground] {
        [
            WidgetBackground(id: "Background1"),
            WidgetBackground(id: "Background2")
        ]
    }
    
    func defaultResult() -> WidgetBackground {
        return WidgetBackground(id: "Background1")
    }
}

struct WidgetBackground: AppEntity {
    var id: String
    
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Background"
    static var defaultQuery = BackgroundQuery()
    
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(NSLocalizedString(id, comment: "").description)")
    }
    
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
}


struct LocationQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [LocationDetail.ID]) async throws -> [LocationDetail] {
        LocationDetail.getAllLocations().filter { identifiers.contains($0.id) }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [LocationDetail] {
        LocationDetail.getAllLocations()
    }
    
    func defaultResult() async -> LocationDetail? {
        try? await suggestedEntities().first
    }
}



struct SelectLocationIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Avalanche Reports Location"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Select the location of the displayed avalanche reports.")

    @Parameter(title: "Location")
    var locationDetail: LocationDetail
    
    @Parameter(title: "Background")
    var background: WidgetBackground
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I finally found a solution, it looks like `defaultResult` only works if its return value is `suggestedEntities().first`, I honestly have no idea of why it works this way so I would love a better answer where it's explaining and I would mark it as correct.

```swift
func defaultResult() -> WidgetBackground? {
    suggestedEntities().first
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how did you write the LocationQuery so I am not sure why this is happening to BackgroundQuery and not to LocationQuery. But you may add something like this in order to ensure parameter defaults to the value you want:

```
@Parameter(title: "Background", defaultValue: BackgroundQuery.defaultResult())
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. And maybe share the LocationQuery too.

Comment: I added the LocationQuery implementation. I tried your suggestion but I get "Instance member 'defaultResult' cannot be used on type 'BackgroundQuery'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Comment: Seems like properties need to be compile-time constants.  So I think this should solve this problem:                                                                                          @Parameter(title: "Background")
var background: WidgetBackground = BackgroundQuery.defaultResult()

Answer (score 0):

The return type of defaultResult must be optional

```
func defaultResult() -> WidgetBackground? {
    WidgetBackground(id: "Background1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func entities(for identifiers: [String]) ->  [WidgetBackground]  {
    [
        WidgetBackground(id: "Background1"),
        WidgetBackground(id: "Background2")
    ].filter { identifiers.contains($0.id) }
}
```

first, if the function return emtry array will get the msg.
if you run widget with other identifier, filter will return empty.